# GoogleSheet Cell Value Trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

can anyone show me how to create a script to trigger email notification when a cell value (SP) met with the target value(target sp)?

SP Column Formula is as below:

```
function ASXLASTPRICE(asx_stock) {
  var tickervar = asx_stock.substring(asx_stock.indexOf(":") + 1);
  var url = "https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/share/" + tickervar;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var content = response.getContentText();
  Logger.log(content);
  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  var last_price = json["last_price"];
  return last_price;
}
```

Data Sample:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Sending an email when last price get's larger using timebased trigger

- Note: this cannot be a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions?hl=en#advanced)

You can use the trigger event object to control when triggers run so that you are not running when stock exchange is closed.

```
     function asxLastPrice(e) {
      if (e['day-of-week'] < 6 && e.hour > 8 && e.hour < 3) {
        let lp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('lastprice');
        var tickervar = asx_stock.substring(asx_stock.indexOf(":") + 1);
        var url = "https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/share/" + tickervar;
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
        var content = response.getContentText();
        var json = JSON.parse(content);
        var last_price = json["last_price"];
        if (last_price > lp) {
          PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('lastprice', last_price);
          GmailApp.sendEmail('recipient', 'subject', 'message');
        }
        return last_price;
      }
    }

    function createtrigger() {
      if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "ASXLASTPRICE").length == 0) {
        ScriptApp.newTrigger('ASXLASTPRICE').timeBased().everyMinutes(5).create();
      }
    }
```

- [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties?hl=en)
- [time based triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable?hl=en#time-driven_triggers)